# UIScrollView doesn't respond to gestures

Tags: ios, swift, uiscrollview, ios-autolayout

I have a UIScrollView which is a dashboard basically with relevant information for the user. It has a pager underneath and contains three UIViews at the moment.

I used to set the different views with a CGRect as the frame, setting the x offset to the width of the UIScrollView * the page number. This worked fine, but it was a hassle to make the UIScrollView disappear when scrolling in the UITableView underneath.

I am now using AutoLayout with constraints to display the information, which works fine. However, my UIScrollView is not scrolling anymore. It does not respond to any swipe gestures I perform. However, it does respond to taps in the pager, which shows me the offsets and constraints are right, I am just unable to scroll in it. Take a look:

[image: Example]

My UIScrollView is made up like this:

```
var dashboardView: UIScrollView = {

    let dashboardView = UIScrollView()
    dashboardView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    dashboardView.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
    dashboardView.layer.masksToBounds = true
    dashboardView.layer.cornerRadius = 10
    dashboardView.isPagingEnabled = true
    dashboardView.showsHorizontalScrollIndicator = false
    dashboardView.showsVerticalScrollIndicator = false
    dashboardView.alwaysBounceHorizontal = false
    dashboardView.alwaysBounceVertical = false
    return dashboardView

}()
```

I then set the different views like so:

```
for index in 0..<3 {

    let currentDash = UIView()
    currentDash.backgroundColor = UIColor.lightGray
    currentDash.layer.cornerRadius = 10
    currentDash.layer.masksToBounds = false
    currentDash.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    currentDash.isUserInteractionEnabled = false
    dashboardView.addSubview(currentDash)
    currentDash.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: dashboardView.topAnchor).isActive = true
    currentDash.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: dashboardView.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
    currentDash.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: dashboardView.leadingAnchor, constant: dashboardWidth * CGFloat(index)).isActive = true
    currentDash.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: dashboardView.leadingAnchor, constant: (dashboardWidth * CGFloat(index)) + dashboardWidth).isActive = true
    currentDash.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: dashboardWidth).isActive = true
    currentDash.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: dashboardHeight).isActive = true

}
```

When I remove the constraints (AutoLayout) and set it with frames it works perfectly, like this:

```
dashFrame.origin.x = dashboardWidth * CGFloat(index)
dashFrame.size = CGSize(width: dashboardWidth, height: dashboardHeight)
let currentDash = UIView(frame: dashFrame)
```

But then, because of setting the frame, the view doesn't scroll up as I would, which is why I want to use AutoLayout.

Any ideas or suggestions as to what I am doing wrong? My ScrollViewDidScroll() method simply gets not called, because a simple print doesn't return anything in my console.

I have tried setting the isUserInteractionEnabled property to false on the currentDash UIView, which was no success. I have also tried removing all constraints separately, some together, etc. - but also this doesn't work - I need a topAnchor, bottomAnchor, heightAnchor and widthAnchor at least.

Oh, and, of course, I set the contentSize property:

```
dashboardView.contentSize = CGSize(width: dashboardWidth * CGFloat(dashboardPager.numberOfPages), height: dashboardHeight)
```

Any suggestions or hints towards the right answer would be deeply appreciated. Thanks!

**EDIT: I also set constraints for the UIScrollView itself:**

```
dashboardView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: dashboardBG.topAnchor).isActive = true
dashboardView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leadingAnchor, constant: normalSpacing).isActive = true
dashboardView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.trailingAnchor, constant: -normalSpacing).isActive = true
dashboardView.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerXAnchor).isActive = true
dashboardView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: dashboardHeight).isActive = true

dashboardView.delegate = self
```

Comment: A common problem when using Scroll View is not properly defining the constraints.
A scroll view does not have a set height. It gets its height from the content view it is to display. Within this content view a ScrollView needs to know the height and width of the content it is holding in order to know how much to scroll and which direction. Try to re-do your constraints from inside the scrollview out

Comment: Based on your suggestion, I have edited my original post with the constraints I use for the UIScrollView itself. So these should be fine as well, I think.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is here

```
currentDash.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: dashboardView.leadingAnchor, constant: dashboardWidth * CGFloat(index)).isActive = true
currentDash.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: dashboardView.leadingAnchor, constant: (dashboardWidth * CGFloat(index)) + dashboardWidth).isActive = true
```

1- Regarding leading of the views , the leading of the first view should be pinned to the scrollView , the leading of the second view pinned to the trailing of the previous and so on ,  so

```
if index == 0{

   // make leading with scrolview leading
else
{

   // make leading with prevView trailing
}
```

So make a var initiated with scrollView and change end of for loop

2- Regarding the trailing , only the last view trailing be pinned to the trailing of the scrollview

```
if index == 2 { // last 

 // make trailing with scrollView 
}
```

Comment: I will try your solution shortly, in a couple of minutes, but I am wondering why the pager works then. It means the views are shown next to each other, no?

Comment: Just tried what you were suggesting. I created three UIViews separately, firstDash, secondDash and thirdDash and add them all as a subview to dashboardView. I then check the index to set the constraints, resulting in the exact same behavior: scrolling does not work with a swipe, but changing the pager does work.

Comment: I am currently thinking the problem is somewhere in the view I am adding, as it creates an overlay of the UIScrollView or something so the swipe gesture isn't registered to the UIScrollView but to the custom UIView representing the page inside the UIScrollView. Could that be? I did exactly as you suggested regarding the constraints but it doesn't seem to do the job. EDIT: if I have only one UIView inside the UIScrollView and scroll to the last page with the pager (so where the third UIView would be), I can actually use the UIScrollView. Which confirms my idea that the method is not called..

Answer (score 1):

I eventually figured it out thanks to Sh_Khan’s answer. I held on to the original code, but removed the trailingAnchor for all indexes and added it only to the last index.

```
for index in 0..<3 {

    let currentDash = UIView()
    currentDash.backgroundColor = UIColor.lightGray
    currentDash.layer.cornerRadius = 10
    currentDash.layer.masksToBounds = false
    currentDash.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    currentDash.isUserInteractionEnabled = false
    dashboardView.addSubview(currentDash)
    currentDash.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: dashboardView.topAnchor).isActive = true
    currentDash.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: dashboardView.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
    currentDash.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: dashboardView.leadingAnchor, constant: dashboardWidth * CGFloat(index)).isActive = true
    currentDash.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: dashboardWidth).isActive = true
    currentDash.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: dashboardHeight).isActive = true 
    if index == 2 {
        currentDash.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: dashboardView.trailingAnchor).isActive = true
    } 
}
```

Thanks for the help!